# Safari cut web page in iphone 6 plus

Tags: web, mobile-safari, resolution, iphone-6-plus

I have a problem with cut web page after enter the page in browser on Iphone 6 plus. But site is correctly look in Ipad 2 and Iphone 4 and 5. Can anyone help me with this issue? I added <`meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">`.
Thank you for help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD IN TO  section when resize to refresh your page

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
```

Comment: I used your recommendation but it's doesn't work.I added it in header section.<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">. Maybe you have any ideas how can I fixed this issue? Thank you for help.